# Upgrade my Dell Inspiron laptop for PenTesting

Tags: windows, penetration-test, virtualization, kali-linux

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 & wanna upgrade it to start practising pentesing with virtual machines. What do u suggest from specs below to upgrade (I have Kali Linux, Tails OS, XP, Metasploitable etc)...

When I use virtualbox with Kali (attacker) & win xp (victim) the laptop becomes terribly slow.

Operating System

```
Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit
```

CPU

```
Intel Core i5 2450M @ 2.50GHz   60 °C
Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
```

RAM

```
4.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)
```

Motherboard

```
Dell Inc. 0FXK2Y (CPU 1)    61 °C
```

Graphics

```
Generic PnP Monitor (1366x768@60Hz)
Intel HD Graphics 3000 (Dell)
1023MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M (Dell)    55 °C
```

Storage

```
465GB Hitachi HTS547550A9E384 ATA Device (SATA) 42 °C
```

Optical Drives

```
DTSOFT Virtual CdRom Device
MATSHITA DVD+-RW UJ8C1 ATA Device
```

Audio

```
IDT High Definition Audio CODEC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could do and what I am able to make of your question is that you want to be able to run virtual machines in your native OS (Windows 8) with some speed. I'm sure you've figured out by now that running Kali in a VM can use a lot of your host systems resources which you can control by adjusting the RAM allocation the VM has in Virtualbox's settings as well as how many core its allotted to use and several other small setting adjustments you can make. Try out different configurations and see what is the best fit for you. Now if you're really dedicated to learning penetration testing and if your willing to make major system changes then you could install Kali as your native OS and either Dual boot Windows 8 with Kali or remove Windows all together. By doing this you are isolating your Operating Systems without dedicating your session in one to supplement the other.